# Writing to an ImageView in code with Droid

Tags: android, class, testing, imageview

How do I go about writing text to an ImageView in a class?

SO, if I am in the main class, using an Intent, I have this:

setContentView(R.layout.result);
if (currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 22) {
  //Write formatted text into a textbox in the ImageView

Is there a simple line of code for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to draw text into an `ImageView` instead of just using a `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

just read this and you will get your answer ... http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html...